# Persisting list of unsaved files in Session vs Hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, file-upload

**Context**

In my ASP.Net Mvc project i am allowing users to upload files which will then appear in a grid. These files won't be saved to the server until the user clicks a save button. But i want the user to be able to view and delete unsaved files so i need a way to persist them across ajax calls.

**Session Solution**

To achieve this i have done it one way using Session. When a user uploads a file instead of saving it to the server I store the files byte array along with its file name in a list variable. As seen below.

```
 public class CustomFile 
 {
  //The real class has other properties. Removed for readability
    public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
    public string FileName{ get; set; }
    public string ContentType{ get; set; }

  }

 public void FileUploadComplete(CustomFile file)
    {
       List<CustomFile> unsavedFiles = Session["UnsavedFiles"] as List<CustomFile>;

       if(unsavedFiles == null)
           unsavedFiles = new List<CustomFiles>();

       unsavedFiles.Add(file);
    }
```

Now when a user goes to view a file i can read the file from Session as seen below

```
 public FileResult LoadFile(string fileName)
    {
        List<CustomFile> unsavedFiles = (List<CustomFile>)Session["UnsavedFiles"];
        CustomFile requestedFile = unsavedFiles.Single(f => f.FileName == fileName);

        return File(requestedFile.FileBytes, requestedFile.ContentType
                  , requestedFile.FileName);
    }
```

**Hidden field Solution**

This works fine however i am not sure if using Session is appropriate in this scenario as I only need to access the unsaved file list on one page. So it is possible to persist the information via storing my list of "CustomFile" object in a hidden field and then passing that to my Actions.

The main issue with this is i then have to find the correct encoding to use for each file when i convert the byte array to a string to store in the hidden field. And the page can become very large storing the file data.

**Question**

So is using Session in this scenario sensible even though i don't need to access it on any other pages or is there another solution that is better suited?

Answer (score 1):

Storing files in the user session is actually not so good idea. Imagine you have 100 users, that are uploading 5 files each every file is 1Mb. You'll end up with 500Mb of data you need to store in memory or on SQL Server. You should consider storing files in the file system, and in memory you will store only file name (path or guid). I suggest using temp directory to store uploaded files and delete them after some time to clean up disk space.
To clean the files you can save the link to the file to the Cache with `slidingexpiration` parameter

```
 MemoryCache.Default.Add(FileName, FileName, new CacheItemPolicy
                {
                    SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0), // 60 minutes
                    RemovedCallback = RemoveFileFromCacheCallback
                });


 private void RemoveFileFromCacheCallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments args)
 {
     var fileName = args.CacheItem.Key;
     var fullFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

     if (File.Exists(fullFileName))
     {
         File.Delete(fullFileName);
     }
 }
```

So every time when store file time is expired or you remove the file link from cache it will be deleted from temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

Rather using Hidden and Session concepts why not you go with the caching which will do good.